# Python heritage reseting attributes

Tags: python

Here is my code:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    addToList():
        self.list.append(5)

class B(A):
    def __init(self):
        super().__init__()
```

So in this order of events, A has a list with the int 5 in it, but when I init() class B, the list will be reset. Any way I can make A a parent of B without reseting the list? Assuming I really do need to add to the list before initing B.

Comment: There is nothing in `A` at the time `B.__init__` is called. It seems that you misunderstood how _something_ works, but it is not clear what. How about you show the complete code, which produces a result different from what you expect?

Comment: 1. You are missing a `def` and two underscores. 2. You seem to confuse classes with objects (class instances). `A` never has an attribute `list`, but all instance of `A` (and `B`) have.

Comment: In my code I can verify that A has a list with 5 in it. But after doing __init__ in B, the list becomes empty. I actually don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.list = []

    def addToList(self):
        self.list.append(5)


class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

x=B()
x.addToList()
print(x.list)
```

output

```
[5]
```